# How do I draw a colourbar for basemap etopo?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar, matplotlib-basemap

Basemap has an [etopo method](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap.etopo) that draws the [ETOPO1 Global Relief image](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/global.html), suitable to use as a background.  It uses blue tones for bathymetry, greens and browns for dry land areas, and white for ice caps.  The poster produced by NOAA ([290 MiB PDF](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/relief/ETOPO1/posters/ETOPO1_atlantic_centered_36x56.pdf)) includes a colourbar illustrating those.
Is there a builtin or otherwise simple way to include this colourbar within basemap?

[image: low-resolution sample with same image source]

<sup>Low-resolution sample obtained from [NOAA](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/global.html)</sup>